# Why am I getting an error when using &this?

Tags: c++

I know that the `this` pointer is implicitly passed to member functions when they are called. When I try to get the address of `this` pointer (via `&this`), though, I get the compiler error "lvalue required". Why is this?

```
class st
{    
  int a,b;
public :
  void print()
  {      
    cout << &this; //gives lvalue required... why?

    cout << this; //will print address of object.
  }   
}
```

Comment: So, what part of that error message don't you understand?

Comment: If you defined `st *ptr = new st;` and you wanted to print the address of the newly-allocated object, you would use `std::cout << ptr;`, right? `&ptr` is obviously not correct. Why would `this` be different?

Answer (score 5):

`this` is not an lvalue but an prvalue.  From [class.this]:

> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword **this is a prvalue** expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called. The type of this in a member function of a class X is X*. If the member function is declared const, the type of this is const X*, if the member function is declared volatile, the type of this is volatile X*, and if the member function is declared const volatile, the type of this is const volatile X*.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

`&` requires an `lvalue` so you cannot get the address of `this`.

Comment: but my question is why we can not use as this is internally treated  as   "class_name   *const this "  so why i can not use & with this?

Comment: because `&` needs an `lvalue` and `this` is not an `lvalue`

Comment: i got it that it is prvalue but what it means can you please tell me?

Comment: You want to know what a `prvalue` is?  I am having trouble understanding what you are not understanding

Comment: hey once you told me that this is prvalue not lvalue that i got after you explained it but now i am having question that what is prvalue and why we can not change that

Comment: A "prvalue" is a pure rvalue, like `true`, produced on request and not necessarily stored in a particular place. You cannot do `&this` for the same reason you can't do `&true` or `&(printf("hello"))` or even `int a; &(&a)`

Comment: @NeilTerminator Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Because this pointer is a rvalue. this pointer is a constant value, it is passed to the member function like a local variable, so it's value is stored in a memory location that would become invalid when returning from that function.

Answer (score -1):

Presumably you're trying to print out the values in the object. cout doesn't know how to do this, and you have to teach it. 
        cout << *this;
might do this if cout knew how to do it, but you can teach it. Here's an example that is more natural c++. (You should also consider a constructor).

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class st
    {
        public:
        int a,b;
    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const st& val)
    {
        return s << "a:" << val.a << " b:" << val.b ;
    }
    int main() {
        st foo;
        foo.a = 1;
        foo.b = 2;
        cout << "foo is " << foo << endl;
    }
```

Comment: He is trying to `cout &this`, not `cout *this`, and he knows that's what he's
trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to understand his intention. As others have remarked, his intention is unclear. I do think he wants to print out the values in the object. It veers off into a discussion of what a pointer is, and I don't think that's what wanted.Maybe I'm wrong. Sometimes when helping people out, it's good to see past their question, and try to understand what they're trying to do.